# Repolist 0 : but package epel-release-5-4.noarch is already installed

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, yum, rhel

I have ran the following commadns to install the epel-release:

```
# wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

To verify this I ran

```
yum repolist
```

that results the output:

```
repolist 0
```

it should be show some repo here,
what I am trying to install is "pip" command on RedHat, first enable EPEL repository, and then run:

```
sudo yum install python-pip
```

Refer me the solution to install pip or to resolve the problem that described above.

Answer (score 1):

I had to had the epel in a CentOS architecture (more precisely in a XenServer) and I used different flags from you.

Try this (I changed your flags to "-Uvh"):

```
rpm -Uvh epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```